# How to sort on a field in list query in aws-amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

How to sort on a field in amplify graphql api? I am trying to sort on a field while getting a list of an model.

Eg: Sorting on createdDate in listOrder query.

Any help please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@key directive might be what you want.

Suppose you are listing `Order`s of a specific customer by `createdAt` timestamp, and suppose this is your schema:

```
type Order @model @key(fields: ["customerEmail", "createdAt"]) {
    customerEmail: String!
    createdAt: String!
    orderId: ID!
}
```

This will create a primary index with a hash key of `customerEmail` and a sort key of `createdAt` that is managed on your behalf by AppSync resolvers. This will allow you to run this query:

```
query ListOrdersForJack {
  listOrders(customerEmail:"jack@gmail.com") {
    items {
      orderId
      customerEmail
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

Why no explicit `sort` keyword? The sorting will happen automatically because the @key specifies that the field `createdAt` should be used as the sort key. You can refer https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1502 for a similar discussion.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I am looking for. But while pushing the code, I am getting below error

`Schema Errors:
Unknown directive "key".
GraphQL request (5:1)
4: )
5: @key(fields: ["id", "createdAt"])
`

Comment: This link help me resolve compile error [https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1566]

Answer (score 1):

**2021 update**: I tried the solution provided by Yik (where something in Amplify auto-fills **createdDate** provided as a sortKey automatically), but it seems that sorting in AWS Amplify is not working as you would expect.

To save others' time I wrote this longer post with the following model that deals with **1** user that has **M**any notifications.

I used "aws-amplify": "^4.3.1" and "aws-amplify-react-native": "^5.0.3".

### Filtering from 'owner' object

I used the schema below (intended to be one-to-many relationship):

```
type User
  @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String
  lastname: String
  firstname: String
  description: String
  avatar: String
  externalHandles: [ExternalHandle]
  followerCount: Int
  followingCount: Int
  verifiedEmail: String
  createdDate: AWSTimestamp
  enableMessageRequests: Boolean
  --> notifications: [UserNotification] @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}


type UserNotification 
  @model 
  @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID", "createdAt"])
  @auth(rules: [{allow: public}, {allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  text: String
  ---> userID: ID!
  ---> author: User! @connection(fields: ["userID"])
  clubID: ID  
  club: Club @connection(fields: ["clubID"])
  type: NotificationsType
  seen: Boolean
  time: AWSTimestamp
  createdAt: String!
}
```

Then I run 'amplify mock api' to generate queries and see them in the GraphiQ web console (+ I added some dummy data).

Now, if you want to list notifications from the user ('owner' object), **you can specify the sort direction**.

[image]

### Filtering directly

But if you try to list notifications **for the given user directly** (e.g. by using userID as a filter and not by using parent object), **the sort direction is missing**.

[image]

Also as you can see on right, the results are **NOT SORTED AUTOMATICALLY** :

[image]

To solve it, I needed to update the schema, where I added **queryField**: "userNotificationsByDate" which will create a new, separate query. See the updated model below:

```
type UserNotification 
 @model @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID", "createdAt"], queryField: "userNotificationsByDate") 
 @key(name: "byNotifications", fields: ["userID", "createdAt"])
```

Now you will get the **sorted results** - but you still **must specify userID** / or primary key **value** that you had defined in @key directive. *@Key directive/annotation uses the format of ["primaryKey", "sortKey"].* If you will leave the primaryKey value empty, the query will fail. See the results below when using this new generated query:

[image]

### Filtering directly - Repeating primary key on all objects

Finally, if you e.g. want to list notifications (without knowing to which user they belong), you would need to define @key with a **primary key value that is the same in all persisted objects**. See example model:

```
type UserNotification 
  @model 
  @key(name: "justByDate", fields: ["dummyType", "createdAt"])
  @auth(rules: [{allow: public}, {allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  createdAt: String!
  dummyType: String!
  ...
```

and then you would need to create notifications like this (using the same primary key):

```
mutation {
  createUserNotification(input: {
   userID: "d69f62fe21b299",
   dummyType: "ShouldBeSameForAllRooms"}) {
    id
  }
}
```

Note: Besides String, you can also use 'enum' in the schema for this dummy primary key.

If you would use enum, such as

```
enum NotificationsType {
  START_MEETING
  JOINED_ROOM
}

type UserNotification @model 
@key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID", "createdAt"], queryField: "userNotificationsForSpecifiedUserByDate")
@key(name: "byUser3", fields: ["type", "createdAt"], queryField: "userNotificationsByDate") 
  @auth(rules: [{allow: public}, {allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  userID: ID!
  text: String
  clubID: ID
  author: User! @connection(fields: ["userID"])
-> type: NotificationsType!
  seen: Boolean
  time: AWSTimestamp
  createdAt: String!
}
```

you can get notifications that belong to e.g. some group (START_MEETING
or JOINED_ROOM in my example) **SORTED** with the following query:

```
query MyQuery {
  userNotificationsByTypeSortedBtDate(sortDirection: ASC, type: START_MEETING) {
    items{
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

See the results:

[image]